# How to format numeric variable in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have a following (simplified) Terraform code:

```
variable "cluster_id" {
    default = 1
}

resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
    ... some instance properties ...
    tags {
        "Name" = "${format("cluster-%02d", var.cluster_id)}"
    }
}
```

And when I run `terraform apply` the plan shows:

```
tags.Name: "%!d(string=1)"
```

The `cluster_id` in `format()` is not handled as a number so formatting fails. I would expect that I get `cluster-01` but that's not the case.

Am I doing something wrong or is it really not possible to use custom variables as numbers in formatting?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Terraform, pre 0.12, only [supports `string`, `list` and `map` types as an input variable](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#type) so despite you providing an `integer` (or a `float` or a `boolean`) it will be cast to a `string`.

Both Terraform [and Go](https://play.golang.org/p/FQwE-Y5F4Bi) allow you to use the same padding for integers and strings though so you can just use the following to 0 pad the `cluster_id`:

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
    # ... some instance properties ...
    tags {
        "Name" = "${format("cluster-%02s", var.cluster_id)}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I have not seen it yet in the documentation, there was a Github issue where a maintainer showed that the `number` and `boolean` types are working successfully in the current 0.12-alpha. Might be helpful in the future. Found it: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/6254#issuecomment-433503897. Also excited for that `list(string)` capability.

Comment: Yeah, was trying to find documentation on the richer type handling in 0.12 but couldn't see anything for input variables so actually removed that reference to 0.12 at first but this is a nice find, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another option I found is to do `${format("cluster-%02d", var.cluster_id+0)}`. Adding zero produces real number and then `%02d` works correctly. But using `%02s` is cleaner.